# How to create a method that generates an arraylist of random number

Tags: java, arraylist

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> random = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    random = getRandom(100, 100);
    for (int i = 0; i < random.size(); i++)
        System.out.println(random.get(i));
}

private static ArrayList<Integer> getRandom(int range, int size) {
    ArrayList<Integer> randomNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        randomNumbers.set(i, new Random().nextInt(range)+1);
    return randomNumbers;
}
```

Whenever I run this, I get an *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0*

Comment: Initially, when you declare an array list, the back end array is empty. So, when you call add() first element only then array is created of default size. And, as you are using set(), it means that your are trying to set value at an index in an empty array.

Comment: So you may replace set() with add().

Comment: No need to create that ArrayList object in Main, because you return one from your method and assign it to that variable, which "overwrites" the previous value.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
randomNumbers.set(i, new Random().nextInt(range)+1);
```

to

```
randomNumbers.add(new Random().nextInt(range)+1);
```

the `set()` method of an `ArrayList` works an **EXISTING** element of the `ArrayList`, but in your case it's **empty**, which means that the first call to

```
randomNumbers.set(i, new Random().nextInt(range)+1);
```

where `i == 0` is invalid. Use `add()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`Arraylist` are backed by `arrays`, when you use `set` method with an `index`, it tries to set the value at the `index` since the backed `array` is empty you get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, so first you need to populate the `Arraylist`.

For that you need to use the `add` method, instead of `set`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [JDev's correct response above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34086650/2929338), take a look at the description of `ArrayList#set`'s [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,%20E)):

> Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element.

So, the specified index has to already be populated in order for the `ArrayList#set` call to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

```
arrayList.set(index, value) method is used to replace old value with new value. But in your case, you are not replacing a value. You are just simply adding values.
So, Use add method of list.



randomNumbers.add(new Random().nextInt(range)+1);

And for printing the values of Arraylist, you are using:

for (int i = 0; i < random.size(); i++)
        System.out.println(random.get(i));

but no need to iterate it through for loop, You can directly print this like below:

System.out.println(random);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you could also use the functional style:

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0, 100)
    .mapToObj(i -> random.nextInt(100))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will [minimize the moving parts](https://twitter.com/mfeathers/status/29581296216) that are part of what's causing your problem :)

Comment: That’s unnecessarily complicated. Just use `random.ints(100, 0, 100).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: Cool! I wasn't aware of `boxed()`